# Sphinx :ref: reference does not render in bullets (rtd theme)

Tags: python-sphinx, cross-reference

I'm trying to render a set of bullets with links to my other internal Sphinx `rst`files as below:

```
* :ref:`MyTitle <ref-page-intro>` - bla bla bullet stuff
```

The above works without the bullet - but when adding the bullet in front, the reference is not rendered. Any idea how to get around this in a practical way?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the results you claim with this example. The links render just fine for me, with or without the bullet.

Comment: Hm I'm using Sphinx 1.8.5 and the `sphinx_rtd_theme` - maybe it's related to that

Comment: Did you view the rendered HTML source? Maybe it's there but the CSS hides it or has the same background color.